# Finding a 2D Fourier transform with a Contour Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, contour-integration, fourier-transform

I am reading a paper which has a number of two-dimensional Fourier transforms in the appendix.  For example,

$$F\left(\frac{x^2}{r^3}\right)=\frac{k_2^2-k_1^2 z k}{k^3}e^{-kz},$$

where $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, $k^2 = k_1^2 + k_2^2$ and the 2D Fourier transform is defined as

$$\hat{f}(k_1, k_2, z)=F(f)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y,z) e^{ik_1x +ik_2 y} \: dx \: dy.$$

I suspect that these were obtained by treating the Fourier transform as a contour integral in the upper half-plane and was wondering if someone could carry out the integral and show how to do this to get the above result as an example of the method.

Edit: I see how an integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ of a function of $x$ with respect to $x$ can be written as a contour integral along the real axis and a semicircle in the upper half plane if we assume $f$ to be analytic in the upper half-plane except for a finite number of poles.

Here we have a 2D Fourier transform which is defined to be an integral of a function of $3$ variables where the integral is with respect to the first $2$ variables, so how do you write this as a contour integral in the upper half-plane?

Comment: Your functions are not meromorphic, you can't solve them with contour integrals.

Comment: What was that thing which you deleted about the radial property?  I'm slightly confused now as I emailed the author and he said that he determined the Fourier transforms using contour integrals.  Perhaps $x$ and $y$ to be the two variables in the complex plane and $z$ is the parameter?

Comment: The notation seems unclear (possibly the paper's fault rather than yours!). Does that mean that$f(x,y,z)=x^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{-3/2}$ and the Fourier transform of $f$ is $\hat{f}(s,t,z)=(t^{2}-s^{2}z(s^{2}+t^{2})^{1/2})(s^{2}+t^{2})^{-3/2}e^{-(s^{2}+t^{2})^{1/2}z}$?

Comment: Yes, so $f$ is as you say, and the Fourier transform is also what you have written.  The paper in general is not clear at all, I can link the paper if that helps, then the bit which I am interested in is in the appendices.  Surely it must be possible to take a function, plug it into the double integral and then somehow get a contour integral which can be evaluated with the residue theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first your functions are not meromorphic, you can't solve them directly with contour integrals.

The solution is [formula 504 on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Formulas_for_general_n-dimensional_functions)

With $k=(k_x^2+k_y^2)^{1/2}$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}} e^{i(k_x x+k_yy)}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-z (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}} e^{ik y}dxdy$$ $$=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-z r}  e^{i k r\sin t}rdrdt=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{(z-ik\sin t)^2} dt = \int_{|s|=1} \frac1{(z-ik \frac{s-s^{-1}}{2i})^2}\frac{ds}{is}$$
$$= 2i\pi (Res( \frac1{(sz-k \frac{s^2-1}{2})^2}\frac{1}{is},s=0)+Res( \frac1{(sz-k \frac{s^2-1}{2})^2}\frac{1}{is},s=\frac{-z+ (z^2+k^2)^{1/2}}{-k})+Res( \frac1{(sz-k \frac{s^2-1}{2})^2}\frac{1}{is},s=\frac{-z- (z^2+k^2)^{1/2}}{-k}))$$
$$= \ldots$$

Comment: Sorry, could you explain the working in a bit more detail?  What happened with $x^2/r^3$?  Also what happened in the end?

Comment: It is obvious how 504 relates to your Fourier transform pair.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I follow, perhaps because it's a 2D transform of a 3-dimensional function, I don't know that much about Fourier transforms.  I can how the formula gives a Fourier transform but where is the exponential in the final transform?  In the case I have, the Fourier transforms are always something multiplying $e^{-kz}$.

Comment: Wikipedia is saying the Fourier transform of $e^{-kz}$ is $\frac{A}{r^3}$ where $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$, I have shown the main steps for how to obtain it, then multiply $\frac{A}{r^3}$ by $x^2$ which means differentiating two times  $e^{- kz}$

Comment: I think you might be working backwards a bit as $e^{-kz}$ is on the right hand side.  I am basically looking for a simple strategy of taking any function, putting it into the double integral and then obtaining the Fourier transform: for example, what would the 2D Fourier transform of $x/r^5$ be, or $y/r^5$?  So are you saying you basically try to re-write the integrand so it only depends on $r$?

Comment: No. I'm saying the Fourier transform of $e^{-kz}$ has a closed-form which is exceptional, differentiating gives a few other Fourier transform pairs.